# Google Apps Script to Update Confluence Page failed with code 415

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, confluence-rest-api

I'm trying to make a script to update a Confluence page by Google Apps Script. I have a google sheets to store data to be uploaded. I have some code but I ended up with

```
Exception: Request failed for https://<mypsace>.atlassian.net returned code 415
```

I have tried the below code, but I cannot succeeded.

```
const url = "https://<space>.atlassian.net/wiki/rest/api/content/<spaceid>?expand=body.storage";
const token = "<myToken>";
const user = "<myEmail>";
var value = "<myContentInHTMLFormat>"
headers = {"Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(user + ':' + token) };
var payload = {
    "type": "page",
    "title": "<confPageTitle",
    "version": {
      "number": <versionOfPage>
    },
    "body": {
      "storage": {
        "value": value, 
        "representation": "storage"
      }
    }
  };

  var params = {
    "method": "PUT",
    "headers": headers,
    "muteHttpExceptions": false,
    "payload": JSON.stringify(payload),
    "ContentType": "application/json"
  };
  
  try {
    let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
    console.log(response.getContentText());
  } catch(e){
    Logger.log(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please modify `"ContentType": "application/json"` to `"contentType": "application/json"` and test it again. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `Thank you @Tanaike, that worked!`, I understood that your issue was resolved. In this case, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.